# Is it possible to ignore JVM-only properties and safely export to JavaScript?

Tags: scala.js

I have a basic project setup following this [Play with ScalaJS example](https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example). Other examples I have found using this same pattern would separate the case classes (models) from what would traditionally be their companion objects. That is, the case class would live in the "shared" sub-project, and the "companion object" (really just some object) would live in the "server" sub-project.

It would be highly preferable to keep these two within the same file (i.e. put important stuff in the real companion object), as it is very convenient to place type-class instances there and have them resolve properly. For example:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)

object User {

  val default = User(1, "Guest")

  // I need this for the back-end, but don't need to export to JS
  implicit val reads: Reads[User] = ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this leads to a linking error, as the `Reads` type exists solely on the JVM (just one of many). But, if I were to move `val reads` into a different file, the implicit resolution of `Reads[User]` would break throughout the "server" sub-project, without adding explicit imports (which would be annoying).

Is it possible to explicitly ignore certain properties in the ScalaJS export, while still allowing them to compile for the JVM? I'd like the `User` case class to export, and possibly even other properties of its companion object, but others that exist on the JVM only could be ignored without disrupting the front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have worked around this in the past (in the Scala.js codebase itself), is by a `PlattformExtensions` trait that mix into the cross compiled object but is different for JVM and JS:

```
object User extends UserPlattformExtensions {
  val default = User(1, "Guest")
}
```

In your JVM project:

```
trait UserPlattformExtensions {
  implicit val reads: Reads[User] = ???
}
```

In your JS project:

```
trait UserPlattformExtensions
```

In your file organization (with a standard cross project), this would look like the following:

```
project/
  shared/
    src/main/
      User.scala
  jvm/
    src/main/
      UserPlattformExtensions.scala
  js/
    src/main/
      UserPlattformExtensions.scala
```

There are no dependency issues, since to the compiler, the source files are assembled as follows:

```
sources in projectJVM:
  shared/src/main/User.scala
  jvm/src/main/UserPlattformExtensions.scala

sources in projectJS:
  shared/src/main/User.scala
  jvm/src/main/UserPlattformExtensions.scala
```

So to each individual compilation run, this whole construct is simply an object that inherits from a trait. Which source directories the sources come from do not matter to the compilation.

Comment: Interesting. I'm still unclear on how I can make this work, though. If `object User` lives in the shared project, and the JVM and JS projects both depend on the shared project, how is the trait found without a circular dependency?

Comment: I addressed this in the answer directly.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense to me. It'll be a matter of changing my project structure to accurately fit this model. Thanks!